# How do I get the contents of multiple tables in SQL based on Metadata of the tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, metadata

I have a task in school where I am supposed to extract the contents of a table `SalesLT.Customer` as well as the content from any table related to it by foreign key. I am supposed to do this in one query. This is the code I used to find related tables.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE object_id IN
(SELECT parent_object_id
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('SalesLT.Customer'))
```

The related tables are `CustomerAddress` and `SalesOrderHeader`. I don't understand how I am supposed get the contents of the three tables based on this. Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL and SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Use joins? Sure you can't get relations AND data in same query.

Comment: This looks like a very roundabout way of asking for an `inner join`